# Evaluating multiple filters in a single pass

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below rdd created and I need to perform a series of filters on the same dataset to derive different counters and aggregates.

Is there a way I can apply these filters and compute aggregates in a single pass, avoiding spark to go over the same dataset multiple times?

```
val res = df.rdd.map(row => {
    // ............... Generate data here for each row.......
})

res.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
val all = res.count()

val stats1 = res.filter(row => row.getInt(1) > 0)
val stats1Count = stats1.count()
val stats1Agg = stats1.map(r => r.getInt(1)).mean()

val stats2 = res.filter(row => row.getInt(2) > 0)
val stats2Count = stats2.count()
val stats2Agg = stats2.map(r => r.getInt(2)).mean()
```

Comment: why are you converting to an RDD? if you leave it as dataframe the spark optimizer would take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate:

```
 case class Stats(count: Int = 0, sum: Int = 0) {
     def mean = sum/count
     def +(s: Stats): Stats = Stats(count + s.count, sum + s.sum)
     def <- (n: Int) = if(n > 0) copy(count + 1, sum + n) else this 
 }

 val (stats1, stats2) = res.aggregate(Stats() -> Stats()) (
   { (s, row) => (s._1 <- row.getInt(1), s._2 <- row.getInt(2)) },
   { _ + _ }
 )

 val (stat1Count, stats1Agg, stats2Count, stats2Agg) = (stats1.count, stats1.mean, stats2.count, stats2.mean)
```